# Failed to execute CommandLineRunner in jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I've a problem with run my application in .jar file. When I am running it in IntelliJ I don't have any problem. It is result of running my app by .jar How can I fix it? I am using JsonNode  and restTemplate to get information from json and creating object.

```
Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.rafalpodgorski.weatherclient.WeatherClientApplication.main(WeatherClientApplication.java:17) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[weatherclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[weatherclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[weatherclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[weatherclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:310) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at com.rafalpodgorski.weatherclient.service.TemperatureService.getTemperature(TemperatureService.java:42) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.rafalpodgorski.weatherclient.service.TemperatureService.getTemperatureByCityName(TemperatureService.java:31) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.rafalpodgorski.weatherclient.WeatherClientApplication.getTemperatureForCity(WeatherClientApplication.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.rafalpodgorski.weatherclient.WeatherClientApplication.lambda$run$0(WeatherClientApplication.java:37) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

My running class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.application")
public class WeatherClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WeatherClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static Temperature getTemperatureForCity(TemperatureService temperatureService, String city) {
        if (city.equals("auto")) {
            return temperatureService.getTemperatureByGeolocation();
        } else {
            return temperatureService.getTemperatureByCityName(city);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(TemperatureService temperatureService) {
        return args -> {
            for (String city : ConfigReader.readConfig()) {
                Temperature temperature = getTemperatureForCity(temperatureService, city);
                System.out.println(temperature);
                temperatureService.saveTemperature(temperature);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

TemperatureService:

```
@Service
public class TemperatureService {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private GeolocationService geolocationService;

    public TemperatureService(RestTemplate restTemplate, GeolocationService geolocationService) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.geolocationService = geolocationService;
    }

    public Temperature getTemperatureByCityName(String cityName) {
        String url = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&APPID=%s&units=metric", cityName, API_KEY);
        return getTemperature(url);
    }

    public Temperature getTemperatureByGeolocation() {
        Location location = geolocationService.getCoords();
        double lat = location.getLat();
        double lng = location.getLng();
        String url = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%.2f&lon=%.2f&APPID=%s&units=metric", lat, lng, API_KEY);
        return getTemperature(url);

    }

    private Temperature getTemperature(String url) {
        JsonNode info = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonNode.class);
        String cityName = info.get("name").asText();
        int temperature = info.get("main").get("temp").asInt();
        return new Temperature(cityName, temperature);
    }


}
```

I think that something is wron with JsonNode because when I did use map for mapping this problem will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into your error stacktrace..

It shows `404 Not Found` Exception. (take a look into your stacktrace you posted).

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:85) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

this means the REST-Api you try to hit is not available.

Now come to this line of code (what you try to do)..

```
private Temperature getTemperature(String url) {
        JsonNode info = restTemplate.getForObject(url, JsonNode.class);  //url not Found.
        String cityName = info.get("name").asText();
        int temperature = info.get("main").get("temp").asInt();
        return new Temperature(cityName, temperature);
    }
```

here in above code there is no response from `url` (Cause : Not available).
After getting `null` as a response you try to parse.

here there is not exception handler which able to handle that `404 Exception`. so, exception must handled by default handler of jvm.

More about Error Response Code 404 [Click Here](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/websites/website-creation/what-does-the-404-not-found-error-mean/)

Comment: I know but why? When I run it in IntelliJ it works fine.

Comment: What should I am doing with it?